# ListView.ItemDrag event raised on fast clicking

Tags: vb.net, listview, drag-and-drop

I have Drag and drop functionality implemented on my ListView object. The event which starts everything is ListView.ItemDrag. Usually it works fine but when I single-click on my list view really fast, from time to time ListView.ItemDrag event is raised.

Do anyone why and how to prevent it from being fired?

Comment: I am not sure how one does a *single-click really fast* but most likely it is because the mouse moves ever so slightly while the button is down.

Comment: I was really careful to ensure that didn't happen. I'm 100% confident it is not the reason

Answer (score 0):

Whether the most moves, the mouse sends bad data, or there is a timing bug that makes Windows think the mouse moved, vb.net believes the mouse moved during the click, creating a drag event. You can ignore the event in the ItemDrag handler.

If the problem is that the Item Drag event is replacing the click event, you may be able to use the MouseDown event instead of the Click event. MouseDown will fire before the Item Drag event, but MouseClick will not fire if there is an Item Drag event. This may cause problems if you are using a double click handler, however.

Another approach would be to treat the Item Drag event as a Click event, calling the same function for both events. Of course, this assumes the user cannot drag items from the listview.